# Outdent ruby access modifiers in emacs

Tags: ruby, emacs, ruby-mode

Can emacs ruby-mode be configured to outdent access modifiers (`private`, `protected`, `public`)? I would like it to outdent them like so:

```
class MyClass
  def hello; end

private

  def world; end
end
```

I couldn't find any obvious way to do it in ruby-mode or enhanced-ruby-mode.

Comment: I did manage to hack this into enahnced-ruby-mode. It isn't perfect, but it gets the job done for me for now. https://github.com/zenspider/enhanced-ruby-mode/issues/58

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ruby-mode, this would do the trick:

```
(defadvice ruby-indent-line (around outdent-modifiers activate)
  (if (save-excursion
        (beginning-of-line)
        (looking-at "\s*\\(private\\|protected\\|public\\)\s*$"))
      (save-excursion
        (beginning-of-line)
        (just-one-space 0))
      ad-do-it))
```

Most likely it would work with enhanced-ruby-mode too, since the name for the indenting function is the same, but I did not test that.

Comment: This does work for ruby-mode. enh-ruby-mode is trickier, and I haven't figured that one out yet.